# Iterate dicts and extract values without a for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary

From a query I am getting these values:

```
[{'year': 2012L},
 {'year': 2013L},
 {'year': 2013L},
 {'year': 2013L}]
```

Without a for-loop, how can I extract into an array all the `year's` values?

I need to get a list like:

```
[2012,2013,2013,2013]
```

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh: but the OP doesn't have a dictionary, he has a list of dictionaries.

Comment: From where are you getting these query results? Is this an sqlalchemy or django? Could you show the code that is used for getting results? There could be a built-in way to flatten the results (depending on the tool used).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lis = [{'year': 2012L}, {'year': 2013L}, {'year': 2013L}, {'year': 2013L}]
>>> [x['year'] for x in lis]
[2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> l = [{'year': 2012L},
...  {'year': 2013L},
...  {'year': 2013L},
...  {'year': 2013L}]  
>>> [item['year'] for item in l]
[2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L]
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming

```
a=[{'year': 2012L},
{'year': 2013L},
{'year': 2013L},
{'year': 2013L}]
```

using a while loops and pop()

```
   while(a):
      v=a.pop()
      print v['year']
```

with map

```
def rv(x): return x['year']
list(map(rv,a))
[2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L]
```

Comment: Could move that function into a `lambda`:  `map(lambda x: x['year'], a)`

Comment: Wouldn't you need `.pop(0)` to go in the left-to-right order?

Answer (score 1):

[`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) and a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are a good fit for this. It's also easy to extend and get multiple items per iteration (see`itemgetter`doc).

```
from operator import itemgetter

dicts = [{'year': 2012L},
         {'year': 2013L},
         {'year': 2013L},
         {'year': 2013L}]

extractor = itemgetter('year')
print [extractor(d) for d in dicts]  # [2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L]
```